# Came across base64 while checking theme coding. Is this code malicious or not?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was checking code of WordPress theme and came across strings containing base64, I am not expert but heard that it is usually malicious. Can someone glance on these lines of code and tell if it is malicious or not?

```
<div class="tiepanel-item">
    <h3><?php _e( 'Export', 'tie' ) ?></h3>
    <div class="option-item">
        <textarea style="width:100%" rows="7"><?php echo $currentsettings = base64_encode( serialize( $current_options )); ?></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tiepanel-item">
    <h3><?php _e( 'Import', 'tie' ) ?></h3>
    <div class="option-item">
        <textarea id="tie_import" name="tie_import" style="width:100%" rows="7"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
add_action('wp_ajax_test_theme_data_save', 'tie_save_ajax');
function tie_save_ajax() 
{
    check_ajax_referer('test-theme-data', 'security');
    $data = $_POST;
    $refresh = 1;

    if( !empty( $data['tie_import'] ) )
    {
        $refresh = 2;
        $data = unserialize(base64_decode( $data['tie_import'] ));
        array_walk_recursive( $data , 'tie_clean_imported_options');
    }

    tie_save_settings ($data , $refresh );
}
```

Comment: This looks like a back door to allow an attacker to run arbitrary code on your server. But, if you don't know what it is it shouldn't be on your server at all, regardless of whether it is malicious or not. Clean your files, change your passwords, and check your Wordpress installation and all modules for security. And do it __now__.

Comment: if you think you've been hacked then wipe your server and install a secure backup, I would not recommend anything else. It's easy to miss a single line of code or another door to your server that has been made because of the first one. Wipe and reinstall a clean backup.

Comment: I'd say, decode the string and check what comes out. No need to panic just yet. Base64 encoded string by itself do no harm and don't necessarily mean that there's something bad going on. Furthermore, in the code you've posted I don't see anything that could possibly harm your install.

Comment: Thanks guys Really Appreciate your replies.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the import/export settings functionality of your theme. Base 64 is used to encode the serialized string of your theme options - it's a very common practice as it prevent the original data from getting corrupted (base 64 converts text in ASCII which is safe in any database collation).